# SQL server express, cannot read or write in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a code written that automatically adds and reads information from my SQL Server 2012 Express table, Logins. But it wont work, here is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=myComputer;" + "server=MYCOMPUTER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "database=loginTest; " + "connection timeout=5");
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Logins Values ('John','Password','Admin')", myConnection);
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand("select * from Logins",
                                                     myConnection);
            myReader = myCommand1.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(myReader["Column1"].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(myReader["Column2"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex1.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I have debugged the program and it all seems to go through fine, it skips over :

```
        {
            MessageBox.Show(myReader["Column1"].ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(myReader["Column2"].ToString());
        }
```

for some reason, and it doesnt write the values i told it to.

Can anyone tell me why? Im a beginner at SQL, so go easy please :)

PS It doesnt fire out any error codes or exceptions

Comment: you never [execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) the `INSERT` command

Comment: offtopic tip: try not to pollute your code with so many try-catch blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `Logins` table doesn't have any records, if you mean you want to try inserting some record first to test, it's this line causing your problem:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Logins Values ('John','Password','Admin')", myConnection);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();//Do this to insert something into your Logins first.
```

Comment: Thank you! So why does it need to do that?

Comment: @user2827904 calling `ExecuteNonQuery` will **officially** run your query against your table. You should search more on `ExecuteNonQuery`. Of course as I said, if your table had some records, your code would work but it didn't. Inserting that way **is just to make sure there is some record for testing the next SELECT query**, normally we don't do such a thing (insert first and select right after that)

Answer (score 4):

> it skips over  [...]

Presumably that's because there's no data to read, so `myReader.Read()` just returns `false`.

> it doesnt write the values i told it to.

You don't actually tell it to write anything. You create a `SqlCommand` to insert data, but you never execute it. You need to use `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`. You should also use `using` statements for the commands, the connection and the reader, to make sure they get closed properly.